# How to download a youtube video via terminal

Tags: command-line, video, downloads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I download the videos from YouTube?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177659/how-can-i-download-the-videos-from-youtube)

I would like to **download** this **video** http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_N5dvvqV7g  using commands 
How i download this video via **terminal**