# How can I download the videos from YouTube?

Tags: downloads, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I download Youtube videos?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31077/how-can-i-download-youtube-videos)
>   [Downloading a youtube video](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63270/downloading-a-youtube-video)

I want to download some educational videos from YouTube or any other web site. I am using Ubuntu 12.04. Please explain how to do it.